# Make HTML formatted PDF in itextpdf

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

I have the following code to make a pdf using itext pdf(5.5.4)

```
final String text = "<p><s>asdfadfadf</s> <strong> adfa adf</strong><strong style=\"color: rgb(161, 0, 0);\">adf\n" +
            "adf a</strong></p> ";
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));
document.open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1); transTable.setHeaderRows(1);
table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text)));
document.add(table);
document.close();
```

The html text is not formatted properly. I have found that **flying saucer** can be used to create pdf from html text, e.g. [this](http://blog.jaspertimmer.nl/2013/09/using-flying-saucer-and-itext-in-java.html).

Above code snippet is part of a larger pdf generation class that create multiple tables. All examples I have found regarding flying saucer uses something like following

```
    final ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlString);
    renderer.layout();
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream fos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(html.length())) {
        renderer.createPDF(fos);
        System.out.println(new String(fos.toByteArray()));
        return fos.toByteArray();
    }
```

My question is that how to make the above code integrate with flying saucer. I have already created the Document object. Is there any way this object can be passed to flying saucer library.(with minimal modification)

Comment: You currently plan to use iText + flyingsaucer but did you know that you could achieve the same without any coding as well? You could perfectly format your text using iText DITO since it allows you to design your PDF in a WYSIWYG editor. Check it out: https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-dito

Comment: *"The html text is not formatted properly."* - well, you do `new Phrase(text)` and no one ever claimed that `Phrase` supports html. Thus, the text *is* formatted properly, *as plain text*.